# Changing WordPress URL structure while maintaing the proper 301 redirects with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I currently have a blog set up with WordPress using URLs like so:

> > www.domain.com/blog/?pid=384092817

This was before I knew anything about anything.  There's a significant amount of content there now and I want to change my URL structure to:

> > www.domain.com/my-post-title-384092817

Is there a way to set up my .htaccess and mod rewrite so when users go to the first url they get a 301 redirect to the second URL?  I know to change my WordPress address (URL) setting from www.domain.com/blog to www.domain.com and my permalink setting to /%postname%-%post_id%, but how do I tell the old URLs to redirect to the new ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your WP version, you can just use the [Permalink redirect plugin](http://scott.yang.id.au/code/permalink-redirect/) -- should do the trick for you within WordPress and without mod_rewrite. However, as of WordPress 2.3, a lot of this [should work automatically](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2007/09/25/wordpress-23-canonical-urls/). At that point, the only thing you should have to do is redirect all your /blog/... requests to the route, which you can do via mod_rewrite roughly like this:

```
RewriteRule ^blog(.*) $1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you actually mean that when users go to the second URL, it will be rewritten to the first? That can be done with

```
RewriteRule /blog/.+-(\d+)$ /blog/?pid=$1
```

If you want to send 301 redirects from the old URLs to the new ones, then you can't really do that with an .htaccess file. The reason is that Apache's mod_rewrite doesn't have access to the title of your post, so it won't know what title to insert in the URL. You'd have to do that redirect with PHP.

*EDIT*: y'know what, actually that's not entirely true. You can do some pretty crazy things with the [`RewriteMap` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap), such as instructing Apache to ask an arbitrary program to perform the rewriting, and in that way you *could* have, say, a PHP script that does some database work to figure out what the title is and rewrites the URL appropriately based on that. But that seems like a way overcomplicated solution and I wouldn't suggest doing it - it'll be much cleaner and easier to just send the redirect directly from PHP.

Comment: I need this url: /blog/?pid=234 to 301 redirect to this url: /my-post-title-234

Comment: Guess I misunderstood your question at first, but look at my edited answer: basically you can't (or at least shouldn't) do that with mod_rewrite.

Comment: what about a simplified version?
Going from /blog/?pid=123 to /index.php?p=123 and then letting WordPress handling the rest...